# What is the relationship between computation and Gödel's incompleteness theorems?

Tags: logic, computation, goedel

**In what way do Godel's incompleteness theorems impact computers/hypercomputers?**  Do they somehow prevent them from being capable of computing everything (of computing literally all uncomputable/undecidable/illogical/logically impossible things)?

To ask this in another way, **if Gödel's theorems "vanished" or otherwise did not hold, would that mean that computers/hypercomputers would be able to compute literally all uncomputable/undecidable things?**

To take it a step further:  **Is it only Gödel's theorems that stop us from computing illogical/logically impossible things?** For instance, without Gödel's theorems, could we compute things that are (logically) impossible to depict/describe/compute/conceive (like a circle cutting a straight line in 3 points in Euclidean geometry, which is impossible to draw/depict)? Could we compute illogical/logically impossible things that are (logically) impossible to depict/describe even by words?

Comment: "If Gödel's theorems vanished or did not hold ... would computers/hypercomputers be able to compute all undecidable things ?" As stated, the answer is trivial : YES. If there is no death, we will live forever.

Comment: [Gödel’s Incompleteness Theorems](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/) is a Mathematical theorem that applies to consistent formal systems with some "minimal" expressive capabilities. Assuming that a real compueter is the physical implementation of a formal system, then also a computer is subject to the theorem. Having said this, what are "impossible things" ? Obviously a real computer compute "possible computations".

Comment: If Euclidean geometry is consistent, there are no circles cutting a straight line in 3 points (irerspective of G's Th) and thus **no** computer whatever can compute three distinct intersection points, because there are only two.

Comment: This is probably the third time this question has been asked. Can someone tell me what is driving this question? Is it some current philosopher's work? Why would a computer be able to transcend reality? Who says they can?

Comment: I think this NASA department used to be called "Logical Methods", now it's called Formal Methods. I don't know exactly what they do. https://shemesh.larc.nasa.gov/fm/fm-now-contract.html

Comment: @Richard A version of Gödel's theorems have passed into popular culture, but in the popular imagination, they are a mystical force, capable of defeating science, mathematics and computing, like a holy relic warding off a vampire.  And conversely, without that relic standing in their way, computers would become all-powerful.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Sometimes you have to answer the question people *think* they are asking, not the one they actually asked... :)

Comment: I think that this is a pretty good question. Maybe you could distill it into a single question, without a decision tree.

Comment: @Richard No, it is the fifth time, not counting clones on other SE including under a different user name. It seems to be driven by one really persistent person.

Comment: @Conifold Yeah it sounds like somebody's hobby horse. I thought it might be someone famous that I've not heard of who is being echoed.

Comment: @Conifold Maybe you could provide links to the other five similar questions. It sounds like people have already done serious thinking about this.

Comment: It is fairly common knowledge that logic doesn't work in every situation, what Gödel did was simply to prove that _logically_. For computational devices, it means that they are susceptible to "undecidability" and the "halting problem". That is: sometimes a computer will "hang" and sometimes the computation "will never stop"..., and then an outside agency will have to make a decision to influence to computer, e.g. you press the reset button. And then people look at want went wrong and _enrich/expand_ the computer's logic/language/hardware/software... - That is all there is to IT.

Comment: @MarkAndrews Click on the asker's username, and look at the questions with "computation" and "impossible" in them, for example, [Can hypercomputation compute the impossible?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/61781/9148)

Answer (score 2):

**Gödel's theorems don't have agency, or cause any effects**.  There's nothing magic about them.  What they are is a clever way of *demonstrating* that there are pre-existing, intrinsic limits to what can be computed.  You might imagine being in a field with a fence.  The field is computing, the fence is the boundaries of what can be computed, and all the problems you are considering are sheep.  You don't know if every sheep is inside the fence or not.  Gödel's theorems are a way of identifying a specific sheep that must be outside the fence.  That proves that not every sheep is inside.  In other words, by identifying a particular problem that computing cannot solve, Gödel's theorems prove that not every problem is computable.

**Problems that are logically impossible are also not computable, but for reasons outside of Gödel's theorems**.  They are like sheep that don't exist.  They cannot be said to be either inside or outside the fence, because they don't exist at all.  Their impossibility has nothing to do with Gödel's theorems, one way or another.  To put it another way, even if we couldn't find that one sheep outside the fence, it wouldn't mean that imaginary sheep would suddenly appear inside the fence.

The most straightforward answer to your counterfactual about what would happen  if Gödel's theorems didn't exist is that **there would still be problems that were uncomputable**, we just wouldn't be aware that they exist (unless we found a different counterexample than the one that Gödel constructed). Gödel's theorems are not the fence --they don't establish the boundary.  They just demonstrate that it does exist.

Comment: but if somehow Gödel's theorems would be invalid on a computer/hypercomputer and couldn't be applied to its type of computability, wouldn't that mean that this computer/hypercomputer would be capable of computing all (even logically impossible problems)? @ChrisSunami

Comment: @SueKDccia I have already directly addressed this question in my answer, above.  If it doesn't satisfy your concern, please clarify why.